# Angular redirects on Push State

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

I am working with angular and used $location module and $routeProvider. I am using Ajax calls to fetch data on the page(search function). And want to change the "url" being displayed.

window.history.pushState works fine in displaying the url, but then it redirects the whole page.

I want it to display the new url without redirection.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using actual params there in the URL for that. I.e. using "$location.search()?" - this results URL in form e.g localhost:3000/main?foo&bar and you can change the "foo" and "bar" without redirecting the browser. If you change actual path, as it says, it is a different path from view routing point of view. Therefore you have the option to use '?' and '#' for having content parameters there instead of encoding everything into path.

Comment: I think you I was not descriptive enough, I am using $http to get data in ajax, but I want the user be able to share his link with others and they should be able to see the same content hence I wasnt to update the URL in the browser. But as $routeProvider can see the change in the browser too it refreshes the page.

Comment: Could you give an example of the URLs you are dealing with? I.e. what is the current URL, and what you want to do with the URL? E.g. if you just want to have access to the URL without reloading etc., you can have it with $location.absUrl() -method and calling it like var myUrl = $location.absUrl(); will result you having the full URL and there are no redirects taking place.

Comment: well URL looks like this.
localhost:3001/foo/bar
Now I have search filters on page which changes the values params foo and bar and will result in
localhost:3001/foo1/bar1.
which the $routeParam takes as a valid path and redirects the page as well. The parameters list is very long though.

Comment: Have you considered using actual params there in the URL for that? I.e. using $location.search()? This results URL in form e.g localhost:3000/main?foo&bar and you can change without redirecting the browser. If you change actual path, as it says, it is a different path from view routing point of view and hence you have the option to use '?' and '#' for having content parameters there instead of encoding everything into path.